# manipulating test steps with xray cloud

Tags: testing, jira, jira-xray

I am trying to add tests steps to a Test issue on Jira-Xray on the fly, so I will be able to import tests results by steps (i dont know how many steps I'm going to have before running the test).
I found that API endpoint for Jira server: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/v2.0#/Test%20Step/post_test__testKey__steps
, but I couldn't find the equivalent for Jira cloud.

Answer (score 1):

For Jira cloud Xray provides a GraphQL API that allows users to perform CRUD operations directly on Xray entities.
Regarding your specific question please check: https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/doc/graphql/addteststep.doc.html

One example based on the above documentation is the following:
[Using postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nynDB.png)

Entry point for the GraphQL API documentation: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/GraphQL+API

Here you can find some Postman collections that exemplify usage of Xray Test Management public APIs: https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-postman-collections